# With properties in obj-c, do we need to declare the instance variables?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, properties

With properties in obj-c, do we need to declare the instance variables?

Eg if my .h file looks like this:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *someId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *expires;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *someString;

...
```

Is that fine? It compiles and works, is it the 'done thing' ? Or should i really be doing the below:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
    NSNumber *someId;
    NSDate *expires;
    NSString *someString;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *someId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *expires;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *someString;

...
```

Is there any difference in either of the above ways, if i plan to always use the property accessors?

Does the @synthesize take care of creating the instance vars for me?

Comment: Please [search before posting](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bobjc%5D+property+declare+ivar) [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031230/) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336922/) [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299487/) [4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333797/) [5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706816/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You understood correctly, `@synthesize` takes care of creating `ivars` for you. (That's a new feature of the runtime that's compatible with 64 bits Macs and iOS devices.)

What's nice with that, is that you can @property in your [class extension](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2009/09/11/class-extensions-explained/) and hide your ivars completely from the .h, separating completely the interface from the implementation.

You can also remove completely the '{}' from the .h, making it really clean.

Comment: If i do that, will it prevent me from accessing the ivar in my .m file? I would like to be forced to use the property eg 'self.blah'

Comment: No, you can still access the raw ivar if you feel the need.

Comment: You can still rename the iVar with a statement like @synthesize myProp = _myProp, to prevent accidental use without the getter.   The iVar will be named _myProp.

Answer (score 1):

Found this in the apple docs:

With the modern runtime, if you do not provide an instance variable, the compiler adds one for you